# What does "thin-groined" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm currently reading Flann O'Brien's *At Swim-Two-Birds* and come across this term in one of Sweeney (Shuibhne)'s verses (p. 82, Penguin Classics 2001). Here Sweeney seems to be lamenting his misery and using this term to refer to his own condition (i.e., turned by St. Ronan's curse into the shape of a bird):

> Forgive me Oh great Lord,
>   mortal is the great sorrow,
>   worse than the black grief -
>   Sweeney the thin-groined.

(*At Swim-Two-Birds*, p. 82, Penguin Classics 2001)

Comment: What does "groin" mean?

Comment: OK. I'm just trying to make sure this is not a metaphorical expression ...

Comment: It's not a common idiom (in modern US English), so it's impossible to say if there is some metaphorical meaning, especially in language that appears to be faux-archaic.  (Or it could be an Irish idiom.)  The literal meaning is something akin to "weak-legged", or simply "thin-bodied", but it could have a metaphorical meaning of "timid" or "cowardly".

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks a lot. I think "weak-legged" makes a lot of sense here, judging from the context. Sweeney, then a man-bird, sang those verses to complain about his "prolonged journey". I will do more searches. Thank you for your comments! <3

Comment: I found the usage also in [The Gentleman's magazine](https://archive.org/stream/gentlemansmagaz170unkngoog/gentlemansmagaz170unkngoog_djvu.txt)..." the thin groin of one poriicuhtr word."   Whatever that means. The other hits for "thin groin" are all medical related.

Comment: @Cascabel "poriicuhtr" is almost certainly an OCR misread.

Comment: @HotLicks Then that _poriicuhtr_ text is a minefield of OCR misreads.

Comment: @Cascabel - Yep, in the line above you see "if not in this Q|>eech, as&urediy in the one which precedes it".

Comment: ...and here I was thinking it was Gaelic or sumpin. @HotLicks :O

Comment: @Cascabel Thank you for your comment. I also  think "poriicuhtr" in the quote is an OCR misread, of the word "particular", perhaps? :)

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Thanks for your suggestion. In fact I did and I think I have read all I could find, including those entries associated with architecture. But as this term was used by an Irish author in the 1930s to describe a man-bird in Irish mythology (as I stated in my question), I don't think architecture-related interpretation makes much sense here. Thank you anyway and I will keep searching. Ta~

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to have said, since neither the topic nor my home page seems to remember it better than I do…

Nevertheless, I suggest the fact this was used by an Irish author in the 1930s to describe a man-bird in Irish mythology makes it not less but very much more likely this is architecture-related, as you will discover when you read more Irish literature in English.

Comment: Note that this is 'poetry', and frankly most anything can go here.

Comment: Some Flann O'Brien context for those unfamiliar:
https://english.stackexchange.com/a/462144/230552 (Full disclosure - my own answer.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's got any clear answer, but assuming he's a bird, one starts wondering if bird's groins can be described as thin which is a totally weird train of thought and perhaps that's the intention. Flann o' Brien wasn't known for sticking to 'reasonable rules' of standard English. I wonder if it might be worth posting on the writer's site.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't know where you originally said it or if you even did, but  thin-groined as architecture-related, a thin-groin indicating a structural weakness that may portend collapse, makes sense to me too.

Comment: Thin-Groined, from an architectural-perspective could work. His sanity being that which is thin-groined and on the brink-of-collapse. It's worth adding that as an actual answer, @RobbieGoodwin.

Answer (score 2):

Flann O'Brien's writings tend to make for interesting discussions due to the many layers he places in his works. As a result, I don't think you will be able to find much consensus on minor details such as what this individual term means. That said, I will do my best to offer my take based on the words and context.

If you read through the entirety of this passage (extending a little beyond both the beginning and the end of the cited portion), O'Brien's language suggests "sorrow", "depression", "weakness", and "faintness of heart" as potential contextual meanings for this term. At the same time, it can also suggest physical weakness as Sweeney (the character speaking) is contrasting himself to stags who have the strength to walk where they wish, but he is forced to forever wander.

This is where your quoted text comes in: Sweeney apologizes to God saying, basically, "Forgive me. I know this pain and sadness is only temporary, but this madness feels worse than death and I do not have the strength to fight it." It's worth noting that "At Swim-to-Birds" is heavily pulled from "The Madness of Sweeney" which means the term "thin-groined" may actually be an approximated translation of something mentioned in the original tale.

For context, "The Madness of Sweeney" takes place after "The Battle of Mag Rath" and tells the story of King Sweeney who was made mad by St. Ronan's curse. Much of the imagery in this reflects aspects of that curse such as how he wanders naked (like the stag), treads lightly like a bird (compared to seagulls), and how he can't keep peace (later mentioned "two hand-shaked cranes", as cranes are known for being territorial, but due to the curse, during the war, he'd regularly break the truce forbidding combat during the evening). As he wanders, like a bird, he'd perch himself in trees frequently. His body even growing feathers in the original tale. His world and life effectively fell away from him and now he is less a man and more a beast, and this passage reflects how he laments that his life has turned out this way.

I hope this in some way helps. I understand this isn't quite a precise answer, but I don't know what would be a better way to answer in regards to a man such as O'Brien's writing.

Comment: @ Sora Expansive answer that sends me back to the novel.